# Generic Repository for Lookup Values

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, generics

I have a bunch of Lookup Entities in the database (About 10 in total) that all implement the following interface

```
interface ILookupValue
{
    int Id { get; set; }
    string Name { get; set; }
    string Description { get; set; }
}
```

At the moment i have a repository for each entity that implements an ILookupRepository interface

```
public interface ILookupRepository<T> where T : class
{
    IEnumerable<T> GetLookupData();
}
```

Example Implementation

```
public class CustomerRepository : ILookupRepository<Customer>
{
    public IDbContext _context;

    public CustomerRepository(IDbContext context)
    {
        context = _context;
    }

    public IEnumerable<Customer> GetLookupData()
    {
        return _context.Set<Customer>();
    }
}
```

I don't anticipate any of the repositories needing any other methods, so is there a way of making a generic repository for this scenario without having to have have additional code wiring up repository for each lookup type?

**Edit:** based on Dennis_E's answer, this is what i'm going with

```
 public class LookupRepository<T> : ILookupRepository<T> where T :  class, ILookupValue
{
    public IDbContext _context;

    public LookupRepository(IDbContext context)
    {
        context = _context;
    }

    public IEnumerable<T> GetLookupData()
    {
        return _context.Set<T>();
    }

}
```

Comment: You should put the `ILookupValue` constraint on `ILookupRepository` too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The class looks pretty generic to me.

```
public class LookupRepository<T> : ILookupRepository<T>
{
    public IDbContext _context;

    public LookupRepository(IDbContext context)
    {
       context = _context;
    }

    public IEnumerable<T> GetLookupData()
    {
        return _context.Set<T>();
    }
}
```

Then instantiate with `new LookupRepository<Customer>();`

Answer (score 0):

You will need a generic base class and then have your `CustomerRepository` inherit from that:

```
public class GenericRepository<T> : ILookupRepository<T>
{
    protected readonly IDbContext _context;

    protected GenericRepository(IDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public IEnumerable<T> GetLookupData()
    {
        return _context.Set<T>();
    }
}
```

Then you can create an instance of `GenericRepository<Customer>` directly, or if you prefer, have your IoC container inject that dependency for you.

Answer (score 0):

It looks generic, though one method might come handy when you need to make join statements hitting DB in one go.

One that returns IQueryable

Comment: This is a bit questionable. Arguably it represents data access concerns potentially leaking out of their layer (assuming they have one). I'd say this should probably be done only if necessary.